# Orthogonal Projection Question in Axler:

Tags: linear-algebra

This is Chapter 6 question 17 in Axler:

**Question:** Prove that if $P \in L(V)$ is such that $P^2 = P$ and every vector 
in $\ker P$ is orthogonal to every vector in $\operatorname{im} P$ , then $P$ is an 
orthogonal projection.

Work:

Let $U = \operatorname{im} P$ and naturally want to show that P equals the orthogonal projection $P_U$.

For $v \in V$, write $v = P_v + (v - P_v)$. 
Clearly $P_v \in \operatorname{im} P = U$. Then $P(v - P_v) = P_v - P^2_v = 0 \implies v - P_v \in \ker P$

What should follow is that $\langle v - P_v, P_v \rangle = 0$ for all $P_v \in  \operatorname{im} P$ and thus $v- P_v \in$ the $U^{\perp}$.

However I do not see how $v - P_v \in \ker P \implies$ that $v - P_v$ is orthogonal to every vector in $U$?

Comment: Isn't that given in the question?

Comment: You don't seem to use the fact that $P^2 = P$ at any point.

Comment: He uses it to conclude $P(v-Pv) = 0$.

Comment: As pointed out by user7530, it is given in the exercise that $v \in \mathrm{ker} P$ is orthogonal to $u \in \mathrm{im}P$. You have solved the exercise correctly.

Comment: haha stupid me, lost track of what was given in the question...